# Custom regex to check, add or replace commas

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where I can have multiple input strings. I need to convert all of them to a single format.
E.g.

```
ABCDEF -> AB,CD,EF
ABCD -> AB,CD
ABCDE -> AB,CD,E
AB CD EF -> AB,CD,EF
AB CD -> AB,CD
AB CD E -> AB,CD,E
AB,CD,EF -> AB,CD,EF
AB,CD,E -> AB,CD,E
```

I want to have only one regex for all purpose if possible.

Comment: Please add reason for down vote

Comment: Can you add what you have tried to the question?

Comment: Downvote is probably for not showing any efforts on solving the problem. Please add it. Also what language or tool?

Comment: thanks, will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
(\w\w)(?!\r?$)\W?
```

and use `\1,` as replacement.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uGKAcz/1)

JS code:

```js
var re = /(\w\w)(?!\r?$)\W?/g;
var str = ['ABCDEFDF', 'ABCD', 'ABCDE', 'AB CD EF', 'AB CD', 'AB CD E', 'AB,CD,EF', 'AB,CD,E'];

str.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + " => " + s.replace(re, '$1,'))
})
```

This captures two word characters and matches following optional non-word character which is not a CR / LF.

Breakdown:

- `(\w\w)` Capture two word characters
- `(?!` Start of negative lookahead

  - `\r?$` Match an optional CR and end of line
- `)` End of lookahead
- `\W?` Match an optional non-word character

Comment: Bravo. I learn something every day, etc... I find it very helpful to visualise with tools like regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oM85bB/1

Answer (score 1):

I thought that this couldn't be done with regex alone... see @revo's answer.

You'd be much better off to use the string manipluation tools of your language, for example:

1. Remove spaces and commas
2. Split into 2-character blocks
3. Insert commas between blocks

---

The closest you can get with regex alone is as follows (note the extra trailing comma):

https://regex101.com/r/VJ4sh3/1

Output:

```
AB,CD,EF
AB,CD,
AB,CD,E
AB,CD,EF
AB,CD,
AB,CD,E
AB,CD,EF
AB,CD,E
```

Comment: I know that, just thought it would be better.